# check whether url has men if yes then replace it with women

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do filter based on mens/women in such a way that whenever I click on men then the url should be updated to women by finding men in url and replacing it.

Any help highly appreciated.

```js
$('.men').on('click',function(){
var men = location.href;
  if (men.includes("constraint") === false && men.includes("types") === false && men.includes("vendors") === false){ 
       men += "?constraint=men";
  }
  else if(men.includes("constraint=men") === false && men.includes("+men") === false && men.includes("vendors") === false && men.includes("women") === false){
   men += "+men";
//       women.replace("women","men");
  }
  
  else if(men.includes("types") === true && men.includes("=men") === false){
   men += "&constraint=men";  
  }
  
  else if(men.includes("vendors") === true && men.includes("=men") === false){
     men += "&constraint=men";
  }
    else if(men.includes("men") === true && men.includes("women") === false) {
        
     men.replace("women","men");
  }
  
  else if(men.includes("=women") === true || men.includes("+women") === true){
  alert("url contains women");
  }
  else{
    men += "";
  }
  

       
  var men_result = location.href = men;

  document.getElementById("wow").href = men_result;
   
});
```

Comment: In wich language you wish to do this? What have you tried?

Comment: there's 'men' in 'women' as well... clearly mention your question along with some already tried code...!

Comment: in jquery.
The below is the code

Comment: this appears to be deleted soon, please try improving it before that happens.

Comment: I have improved by inserting my code.

Comment: can you please share the sample url so that we can actually test before sharing!

Comment: well I will make it very clear i.e there are 2 options: men and women. Upon clicking men, the url should be appended with "=men" only if current url is not having "=women". if it is having "=women" then the "=women" in url should be replaced with "=men". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = window.location.href;
if(href.indexOf('men') >= 0 && href.indexOf('women') === -1)
    window.location.href = href.replace('men', 'women');
}
```

Comment: @Arg0n I tried by making use of 'replace' but also its not getting replaced.